# ImportError: No module named qrcode, even though i have the module installed

Tags: python, import

i've been wanting to expand my python skills and thought that making a QR code generator would be fun, however when i try to run the program it gives me this error:

```
    File "heck.py", line 1, in <module>
    import qrcode
ImportError: No module named qrcode
```

so i tried reinstalling the module with pip but it gave me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: qrcode in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (7.3.1)
```

my code looks like this:

```
import qrcode
data = "Buy Dogecoin"
gen = qrcode.make(data)
gen.save('/Users/myname/Desktop/QRcodes/BuyDoge.png')
```

edit: i was using a different version of pip and python, i just reinstalled qrcode module with pip instead of pip3, then installed the image module

Comment: Try renaming your file to something different than "QRcode.py", that may be causing a conflict with your installed module

Comment: @aaossa, QRcode.py isnt the name of the file, it is actually heck.py. i changed it for privacy reasons.

Comment: Please provide more context about what version of python you are using and how you are trying to run the program.

Comment: @kerolloz Im using Python 2.7.18, on the command line im just doing 'python heck.py'

Comment: try running "python3 heck.py"

Comment: I believe you are using pip3 which installs libs for python version 3. That's why when you try running the program (using python 2.7) it says that the required dependencies are not met.

Comment: Call pip and Python with argument `--version` and compare Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Regular installation with pip install .... might not work.

Try with

***sudo pip install qrcode***

or

***sudo pip3 install qrcode***

Based on the version you use.